# Which is the simplest NMEA query sentence, just to detect the presence of the GPS device?

Tags: gps, nmea

I have a GPS receiver, which I want to use with `gpsd` on Linux. It has a 3-state switch: *off-on-log*. On "log" mode, it's sending `$GPGGA`, `$GPGSA`, `$GPGSV`, `$GPRMC`, and `$GPGGA` NMEA messages, once a sec. When I toss the switch into "on" mode, it sends these messages for a while, then stops sending messages.

1. What is the NMEA query, which triggers sending of similar 1-sec messages? I need only position, anyway.
2. Is it possible that old devices does not support such NMEA query or queries at all? It's a pretty old device, with Sirf-II chip.

I can attach to the GPS with `miniterm`, so I can enter queries by keyboard. `$PXEMQTF*6E` (Quick Test) did not work.

[image: Solar GPS receiver]

Answer (score 0):

> When I toss the switch into "on" mode, it sends these messages for a while, then stops.

It shouldn't be stopping.  Something is probably broken.  Normally, no messages are needed to wake up the unit.

> Is it possible that old devices does not support such NMEA query or queries at all?

I've never seen one that doesn't support NMEA.  NMEA 0183 has been around since 1983, predating GPS itself.

SiRF (at least SiRFstarIII and later) supports its own binary protocol as well, but they also support NMEA.

Comment: Switching into "on" mode, it stops *sending* the messages (also edited in the question). I want to use this mode, because, I think, most of GPS devices have no "log" mode, and I want to write a program which I can use with other devices as well.

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong with your GPS unit.  You might try a different one. 
 These days, I'd recommend getting a full GNSS unit anyway.  They're dirt cheap, like $12 online.